# Why does jupyter notebook server keeps crashing when .ipynb files are opened?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was able to use jupyter notebook 4 days ago. The only thing that changed was there was a firefox version update.

After that the server crashes everytime .ipynb files are opened. Even the directory will have a server error. I tried it both on Firefox and Google Chrome, both browsers will crash the server.

My only kernel is python3 and it always says "Kernel Busy". I tried resetting my pc and the jupyter notebook, but nothing seems to work.

[image]

The console showed:

[image]

The last 2 lines are causing the crash but I don't know how to fix it

When I type `conda install jupyter` in the anaconda prompt, I get something before it finishes as shown below. Maybe it might have a cause as to why it is having issues:

[image]

I created a new python environment and installed python, matplotlib, pandas, jupyter and it still crashes

Comment: Does the terminal output anything useful?

Comment: The moment I open the .ipynb file the server already crashes so I don' know what happens there. If i'm not mistaken terminal is the one found in `Developer tools` of the browser if i'm not mistaken? I just get "Can't execute cell since kernel is not set."

Comment: Can you try to downgrade the notebook? `pip install notebook==5.6.0`

Comment: I'm using anaconda but I will downgrade it there. Just taking a long time

Comment: Nope it doesn't fix the issue server still crashes

Comment: This is the closest one buy I don't know how to see what the person saw https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407424/jupyter-notebook-kernel-crashing-non-stop&ved=2ahUKEwjmkfbeqqfiAhVS-2EKHSw2BuIQrAIoADAAegQIBhAF&usg=AOvVaw0mn6qXDXuhD32_53-5jvAe

Comment: @Pherdindy Have you tried change kernels by creating different environment? or as sson as you open jupyter notebook it's gonna get crashed ?

Comment: @Mario as soon as I open jupyter notebook, the server will already crash and show `Python has stopped working`

Answer (score 6):

Please **uninstall and re-install** all the below items:

- ipykernel
- ipython
- jupyter_client
- jupyter_core
- traitlets
- ipython_genutils

Additionally, if you're going to install with conda, follow below command.

`run conda clean -tipsy`

This command will clean up conda caches before you start.

Reference:

1. https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1892

Comment: The issue doesn't get fixed even when I reinstall these packages and run `conda clean -tipsy`

Answer (score 0):

Do you let Jupyter start the browser? If so, disable that and start the browser manually. I don't see how the zmq error messages could be related to the browser startup, but since you say that the only change was a browser update, that's worth a shot.

Check which version of pyzmq is installed. If Jupyter Notebook and the kernel are in different conda envs, check both and make sure they are on the same version and build. Try upgrading or downgrading to different versions. According to [Anaconda issue 8932](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8932), there are problems with pyzmq on Windows. And a new build for win32 was released about two weeks ago - though I would expect win64 builds to be used nowadays.

I also found some recommendations for a similar error message to yours in [Spyder issue 6097](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6097#issuecomment-485227424). The first one is to try without firewall and/or antivirus. You might have picked up a new firewall rule unknowingly. Trying different versions of pyzmq is also mentioned there.

Comment: Only firefox updated, so don't know why it also crashes on Google Chrome. As for downgrading, I have already tried downgrading as suggested previously, but it still crashes. I have also re-installed the components as mentioned in the other answer and even created an empty environment from scratch and only installed jupyter notebook, and it still crashes

Comment: I'll check and try the other recommendations here

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing this solution in case someone needs it in the future.
I have just faced the same problem a hour ago. This was the message I was getting in the terminal. And the jupyter keeps restarting.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.entities'; 'html' is not a package
[I 00:44:32.436 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
```

After Searching through the internet when I can not find the solution. I fixed it by removing the .HTML files I had in the directory. After moving those file jupyter started working parfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem - for me, it was casued by a non-existing %temp% directory (I have %temp% mapped to a ram disk, and the temp folder on it wasn't created yet).

Creating the folder pointed to by %temp% solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

All my environments were working totally fine but suddenly after restarting the system, the jupyter notebook from an environment was not opening or it was suddenly crashing. Tried form anaconda prompt but getting "Unable to create Process...
All my DL dependencies were on this environment and I didn't want to create new environment completely installing all the required dependencies.

Solution: I opened the Anaconda Navigator and cloned old_env to new_env and it worked magically. I could able to open the jupyter notebook successfully and all dependencies were working fine. Hope it helps